# Python exception/ValueError/Error Handling

Tags: python

I have an input (called `names`) and that input is split up into three parts (`.split`) and then the third (last) element is converted into an integer and placed into a list

i.e. for example `names = "John Smith 3"`
     it is split up into three parts `"John" "Smith" 3`
     and put into a list: `list1 = ["John", "Smith", 3]`

Now my question is if the third element is inputted as a string and cannot be converted into and integer (`"John Smith Three"`), how can I go about displaying an error and making the user re-input (names) and also how can I go about handling error if the user inputs `"John Jacob Smith 3"` (more than three elements).

Comment: What is the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you ask the user for two inputs: his/her name first and then the magic number.

If you definitely want to get this from a single input, you could try it like this

```
while True:
    name_and_num = raw_input("Your input: ")
    parts = name_and_num.split()
    try:
        firstname, lastname, num = parts[0], parts[1], int(parts[2])
        break
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        print "Invalid input, please try again"

print firstname, lastname, num
```

Comment: Don't forget also the IndexError :) and I don't think your code ever raises TypeError.

Comment: Thanks, right. :) Casting to int causes a TypeError for argument None, but this won't ever be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

2 Ways to go about this:

This old, classical try catch approach:

```
message = 'Please enter ...'
while(True):
    print message
    user_input = raw_input().split()
    if len(user_input) != 3:
        message = 'Incorrect number of arguments please try again'
        continue
    try:
        num_value = int(user_input[2])
    except ValueError:
        message = 'Incorrect int value'
        continue
    break
```

The other approach is to simply use a regex, it should look like this:

```
import re    
regex = '^\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s*$'
p = re.compile(regex)
print 'Please enter ...'
while(True):
    user_input = raw_input()
    m = p.match(user_input)
    if m:
        value1 = m.group(1)
        value2 = m.group(2)
        int_value = int(m.group(3))
        break
    else:
        print 'Incorrect input format, it should be ...'
```

Not that using this regex, you can match any string having 3 elements separated by any number of spaces and ending with an int value. So `'a b 10'` and `' a  b     10 '` are both matched.

Answer (score 0):

For first part: one easy way of doing this is:

```
try:
    float(l[2])
except ValueError:
    #error - bad input. user must re enter...
```

For second part: just check the length of the list formed from the split.

Comment: blank except clauses are a bad idea. You should be explicit on which exception to catch.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using functions for everything:

```
def processNames(nameString):
  namesList = nameString.split()
  if len(namesList) == 3:
    try:
        namesList[2] = int(namesList[2])
    except:
        print "Third item not an integer"
        return None
  else:
    print "Invalid input"
    return None
  return namesList
```

Say you have a long list of names to loop through:

```
processed = []
for name in longList:
  processed.append(processNames(name))
```

which will gracefully return a list of items with Nones filled in the incorrect entries.