# python3 ValueError value

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to write a function using `python3`, with `exception handling`.
I thought `ValueError` is the right tool to check if the value is in given range, as given [here in python3 doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) which says:

> function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value

So, in this my tiny snippet, I am expecting to use ValueError to check range(0-1) which is not doing:

```
while True:
    try:
        imode = int(input("Generate for EOS(0) or S2(1)"))
    except (ValueError):
        print("Mode not recognised! Retry")
        continue
    else:
        break
print(imode)
```

which yeilds:

```
Generate for EOS(0) or S2(1)3
3
```

Sure, I can do the value checking as:

```
if (imode < 0 or imode > 1):
    print("Mode not recogised. RETRY!")
    continue
else:
    break
```

but the ValueError seems do do this thing.

There are several question on `ValueError` here, but none of them checking "inappropriate value, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165427/python-exception-valueerror-error-handling)
I am a novice and python is not my main language.
Kindly give me some insight.

Comment: What made you think that ValueError knows your range?

Comment: Just use a normal check. Exceptions handlers are used where a normal check with the `if` construct is not enough. In your case is sufficient ;)

Comment: But if you want to prevent conversion errors (you try to convert to `int`, but the user enters a `char`), then you should catch the `ValueError` exception!

Comment: I recommend you to see more about exceptions and how to handle them, then you will understand better when to use them ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstand what `ValueError` (and in general, an `Exception`) is.

`Exceptions` are a way for a method to signal to its caller that some critical error condition has been encountered that would prevent that method from executing as intended. Python's [`try-except-finally`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) control structure provides a way for the caller to detect those error conditions and react accordingly.

`ValueError` is a standard `Exception` raised by various methods that perform range-checking of some kind to signal that a value provided to the method fell outside the valid range. In other words, it's a universal way of signaling that error condition. `ValueError` by itself doesn't do any kind of checking. There are many other standard `Exceptions` like this; `KeyError` signifies that you tried to access a key in a mapping structure (like a `dict` or `set`) that didn't exist, `IndexError` means you tried to index into a list-like structure to an invalid location, etc. None of them actually do anything special in and of themselves, they're simply a way of directly specifying exactly what kind of problem was encountered by the called method.

`Exceptions` go hand in hand with the idiom in python that it is generally considered ['easier to ask forgiveness than permission'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092992/why-is-it-easier-to-ask-forgiveness-than-permission-in-python-but-not-in-java). Many languages support exceptions of course, but Python is one of the few where you will very frequently see code where the `Exception` case is actually a commonly-followed code path rather than one that only happens when something has gone really wrong.

Here is an example of the correct use of a `ValueError`:

```
def gen(selection):
    if imode == 0:
        # do EOS stuff here
    elif imode == 1:
        # do S2 stuff here
    else:
        raise ValueError("Please Select An Option Between 0-1")

def selector():
    while True:
        try:
            gen(int(input("Generate for EOS(0) or S2(1)")))
            break
        except ValueError as e: # This will actually satisfy two cases; If the user entered not a number, in which case int() raises, or if they entered a number out of bounds, in which chase gen() raises.
            print(e)
```

Note there are probably much more direct ways to do what you want, but this is just serving as an example of how to correctly use a `ValueError`.